# How to use DOMDocument to get url in this html

Tags: php, domdocument

My html

```
<td class="end">
<span class="shopName">ダイワンテレコム</span><a href="http://kakaku.com/shop/3211/?used_pdid=K0000575280&amp;uctrl=85427"><img src="http://img1.kakaku.k-img.com/images/itemlist/itemv_btn_sinfo_l.gif" width="102" height="28" alt="詳細を見る"></a>
</td>
```

And I want to use DOMDocument to get `http://kakaku.com/shop/3211/?used_pdid=K0000575280&amp;uctrl=85427`

My php is

```
$atag = $td->getElementsByTagName("a");
$shop_url=$atag->getAttribute("href"); //PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-content\themes\theme-child\cellphone.php on line 172
```

Comment: probably `$atag[0]->getAttribute("href");` - `getElementsByTagName` returns a `DOMNodeList` object

Comment: thanks. please make it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `getElementsByTagName` return a Traversable object (`DOMNodeList`), you can access to the first element with

```
$atag[0]->getAttribute("href");
```

or loop them all with

```
foreach ($atag as $node) {
    //$node->getAttribute("href"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put foreach for `getElementsByTagName` its, a domlist object. Below code will be return all links.

```
<?php
$atag = $td->getElementsByTagName("a");

foreach( $atag  as $searchNode )
{
    echo $searchNode->getAttribute("href"); 
}
?>
```